# Permission error when trying to get TFS custom policy - vsts 2010

Tags: tfs

I have developed a custom policy in the tfs server.

I am trying the following to get a copy of the policy deployed to a developer machine.

VSTS power tools (2010) was used for this

"Team Explorer | Right-Click Project | Team Project Settings | Source Control... | Check-In Policy | Add...

When I click on the Source control menu item in the above flow, the following error is shown.

> Error    Permission AdminProjectRights is required for project
> Testing.

Does each developer need Admin rights to download the custom policy?
If not then which permission is needed to be set for developers

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set any permission for the developers other than the usual contribution rights that they have.

Once you have added the policy to the project (which you need admin privileges to do), every developer will just be able to download it.